# Vertical align image in horizontal nav menu

Tags: css, wordpress, image, navigation, vertical-alignment

I'm having a hard time to align the logo image in the horizontal navigation menu here:

http://fatima-h2020.eu/

Well, this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

but I'm really confused on which element should I edit to achieve this.

Inserting `vertical-align: middle` to the `img` as I've read in other questions just doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Dont style the img - style the a which contains it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Chris still, no luck.

Comment: @Paulie_D you are right, but I really didn't know which part of the code should copy here.. I'll make an effort editing this based on the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sf-menu li:first-child a, .sf-menu li:first-child a:hover {
    padding: 0;
}   
 li.menu-item a {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

also, set margin-top to max 5px-10px on this

```
nav#topmenu{
margin-top:5px;
}
```

Comment: Its getting to it.. I'm just having an thing while hovering on the menu titles. Working on it now..

Comment: just set the same padding on normal and on hover

.sf-menu li a:hover {
    padding: 20px 12px;
}
li.menu-item a {
    padding: 20px 12px;
}

Comment: also remove the border-top of #midsectionhr{
border-top:0;}

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the detailed instructions! Also the border suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

add css in `style.css`

```
.sf-menu a.menu-image-title-hide.menu-image-not-hovered {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Removing the padding gets me closer (s17.postimg.org/mos2otcjz/padding.png) but not exactly what I need here..

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the padding-top and and bottom :)

```
ul li a.menu-image-title-hide.menu-image-not-hovered {
  padding: 0px 12px;
}
```

Comment: Removing the top/bottom padding gets me closer (http://s17.postimg.org/mos2otcjz/padding.png) but not exactly what I need..